# Ajax loading form into div

Tags: ajax, html, position, modal-dialog

I load a div using ajax:
$("#contentdiv").load('MyPage.php');
This is a "modal" div that shows details related to a picture the user clicks on.
The clickable pictures form a long list down my page.

I would like to have this modal div appearing on the position (have the same top value so to speak!!) of the picture that was clicked. Therefore the use does not need to scroll back to his/her picture of interest when the information div is hidden (closed!)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you,

Carly

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) available in the [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) package it should automatically do this for you.